# Holding shift while making a new artboard doesn't create a square artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

Instead of making a square artboard when I hold shift, Illustrator CC will make a new artboard with the aspect ratio of the previous artboard. I've restarted my computer and reset my preferences for Illustrator and it still performs the same way.

Here's an example of what's going on:

[image]

Comment: That's working as intended as far as I'm aware. Thats's how it's always worked for me at least.

Answer (score 4):

The <kbd>shift</kbd> key option to make a new art board will indeed do that. That is the way it works, it relates to the values of the previous art board and keeps ratio.
If you need a square art board create one with radom size then use the keyboard short-cut <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>
The following window will appear.
Insert values of the art board size you want.

[image]